# Best Version For Netbook

Tags: system-installation

I have Gateway LT4010U With INtel Atom N2600 IGB DDR3 memory and 320 GB HDD witch version would be the best...I am thinking of Puppy but I have used Ubuntu before and would like to choose a version from here is there any suggestiolns

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu is very lightweight and works well on netbooks. Lubuntu is even more lightweight. Either is worth a try. I'm about to checkout Mint Mate and Mint XFCE, both of which are supposed to work well on this class of machine.